# Removing ggplot legend symbol while retaining label

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Example code and figure:

```
data <- data.frame( ID = c(LETTERS[1:26], paste0("A",LETTERS[1:26])),
                    Group = rep(c("Control","Treatment"),26),
                    x = rnorm(52,50,20),
                    y = rnorm(52,50,10))

ggplot(data, aes(y=y,x=x, label=ID, color=Group)) + 
   geom_text(size=8) + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
   theme_classic() +
   theme(legend.text = element_text(color=c("blue","red")))
```

[image]

What I'm trying to solve is removing the legend symbols (the "a") and coloring the Group labels (Control and Treatment) as they appear in the plot (Blue and Red respectively).

I've tried:

```
geom_text(show_guide = F)
```

But that just removes the legend entirely.

To keep it simple I could just use annotate...but wondering if there's a legend specific solution.

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=y,x=x, label=ID, color=Group)) +
   geom_text(size=8, show_guide=F) +
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
   theme_classic() +
   annotate("text",label="Control", color="blue",x=20,y=80,size=8) +
   annotate("text",label="Treatment", color="Red",x=23,y=77,size=8)
```

Comment: Related: [Changing the symbol in the legend key in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405823/changing-the-symbol-in-the-legend-key-in-ggplot2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you can tweak the legend key, by hard coding the info you want, although around the other way - keep the key and remove the label.

```
library(grid)

GeomText$draw_key <- function (data, params, size) {
    txt <- ifelse(data$colour=="blue", "Control", "Treatment") 
    # change x=0 and left justify 
    textGrob(txt, 0, 0.5,  
             just="left", 
             gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), 
                       fontfamily = data$family, 
                       fontface = data$fontface, 
                       # also added 0.5 to reduce size
                       fontsize = data$size * .pt* 0.5))
}
```

And when you plot you suppress the legend labels, and make legend key a bit wider to fit text.

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=y,x=x, label=ID, color=Group)) + 
   geom_text(size=8) + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
   theme_classic() +
   theme(legend.text = element_blank(),
         legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

Comment: or (eurgh) you can mess with the grobs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588127/match-legend-text-color-in-geom-text-to-symbol

Comment: I like this answer but I'm struggling to get the Group labels (Control and Treatment) to line up with the "Group" title.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use point markers (instead of the letter "a") as the legend symbols, which you can do with the following workaround:

1. Remove the `geom_text` legend.
2. Add a "dummy" point geom and set the point marker size to `NA`, so no points are actually plotted, but a legend will be generated.
3. Override the size of the point markers in the legend, so that point markers will appear in the legend key to distinguish each group.

---

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=y,x=x, label=ID, color=Group)) + 
  geom_text(size=8, show.legend=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(size=NA) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(colour="") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with [ggplot2 2.3.2](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/ggplot2-3-2-0/#new-features), you can specify the glyph used in the legend using the argument `key_glyph`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, label=ID, color=Group)) + 
  geom_text(size=8, key_glyph="point") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
  labs(color=NULL) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: ggplot showing text legend with dot glyphs instead of the letter a]

For a full list of glyphs, refer to the [ggplot2 documentation for `draw_key`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html).  Credit to [R Data Berlin](https://twitter.com/rdataberlin/status/1402973599368110081) for alerting me to this simple solution.  Emil Hvitfeldt also has a [nice blog post showcasing the options](https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/changing-glyph-in-ggplot2).