# Match ggsurvplot legend text color to line color, include risk table

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, survival, survminer

Related to [this previous post about changing the color of the figure legend text to match graphing colors in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588127/match-legend-text-color-in-geom-text-to-symbol), I would like to extend this to ggsurvplot objects.

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitgraph <- ggsurvplot(fit, 
                       risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE)
fitgraph
```

[image]

What I would really like to do is change the color of the text on the legend to match the color of the lines on the graph.

Using this [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588127/match-legend-text-color-in-geom-text-to-symbol) from Z Cao I can convert the ggsurvplot$plot to a grob, change the legend text color, and then convert back into a ggplot object, which works fine...

```
g1 <- fitgraph

pGrob <- ggplotGrob(g1$plot)
g.b   <- pGrob[["grobs"]][[which(pGrob$layout$name=="guide-box")]]
l     <- g.b[[1]][[1]][["grobs"]]
# get grobs for legend symbols (extract color)
lg    <- l[sapply(l, function(i) grepl("GRID.segments", i))] 
clr   <- mapply(FUN=function(x){x$gp$col},x=lg)

gb  <- which(grepl("guide-box", pGrob$layout$name))
gb2 <- which(grepl("guides", pGrob$grobs[[gb]]$layout$name))
label_text <- which(grepl("label",pGrob$grobs[[gb]]$grobs[[gb2]]$layout$name))

pGrob$grobs[[gb]]$grobs[[gb2]]$grobs[label_text] <- 
  mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {x[["children"]][[1]][["children"]][[1]]$gp <- gpar(col =y); return(x)},
         x =   pGrob$grobs[[gb]]$grobs[[gb2]]$grobs[label_text],
         y =  clr, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
grid.draw(pGrob)
```

Then convert this back into a ggplot object, with color of figure legend text changed to match the color of lines as desired...

```
plot1 <- as.ggplot(pGrob)
plot1
```

[image]

Where I am stuck is now integrating this with the original ggsurvplot risk table underneath, as in the first graph.

My pretty basic reaction was to simply replace the ggsurvplot$plot with the new ggplot object created after extracting the original plot to a grob and then back to a ggplot...

```
g1$plot <- plot1
```

However this does not work...

> Error in `[.data.frame`(g$data[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588127/match-legend-text-color-in-geom-text-to-symbol)], "colour") :    undefined columns
> selected

Most likely due to a loss of the underlying data in the process above, storing only a 2x2 table...

```
plot1$data
  x y
1 0 0
2 1 1
```

Compared to the original `fitgraph$plot$data` which yields the entire data set (hundreds of rows, ongoing survival proportions) which presumably feeds the risk table. The other dumb strategy of `plot1 + fitgraph$table` doesn't work either.

There must be a better strategy - any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Thanks to Stefan for the ggtext solution below, however each of my ggsurvplots has a different color scheme, and applying this method seems to over-ride these, e.g.

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitgraph <- ggsurvplot(fit, 
                       risk.table = TRUE, 
                       palette=c("#B79F00", "#619CFF"),
                       risk.table.col = "strata")
```

For a graph that looks like...

[image]

That looks good but when I then apply the method to change the legend color...

```
cols <- c("#B79F00", "#619CFF")

labels <- function(x, cols) {
  glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {cols}'>{x}</span>")
}

fitgraph$plot <- fitgraph$plot +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = ~labels(.x, cols)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown())

fitgraph
```

This results in a loss of the original graph colors...

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I appreciate your effort the `ggtext` package offers an easy option to achieve your desired result. Besides making it easier to set the legend text colors the final result could simply assigned back to the `plot` element of the `ggurvplot` object:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggtext)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitgraph <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE)

cols <- scales::hue_pal()(2)

labels <- function(x, cols) {
  glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {cols}'>{x}</span>")
}

fitgraph$plot <- fitgraph$plot +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = ~labels(.x, cols)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown())

fitgraph
```

[image]

**UPDATE** In case you pass a custom color palette we have to switch to `scale_color_manual` and pass the colors to the `values` argument. One drawback is that in that case we get a warning as we replace the already existing `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggtext)

cols <- c("#B79F00", "#619CFF")

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitgraph <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE, palette=cols)

labels <- function(x, cols) {
  glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {cols}'>{x}</span>")
}

fitgraph$plot <- fitgraph$plot +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols, labels = ~labels(.x, cols)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown())
#> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour',
#> which will replace the existing scale.

fitgraph
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! One issue I run into with that solution is that it over-rides the color palette I had previously chosen for the graph - have edited my question above to show what I mean. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hej @Timmo83. I just added an update for the case of a custom color palette.